# Flask: POST Many input fields

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have some HTML (Using Flask framework) that shows many input fields. Currently if they click a single "Accept" button, they would only submit that one of course, but I want to add a "Submit All" button, how would I do that?

Upon researching I see that every button must have a unique ID, so I cannot even begin, how would I do a unique ID? I looked that up to no avail and even tried assigning some VAR in my flask that is passed to HTML with no luck, any ideas?

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="content has-text-centered">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Fields</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Fields</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    {% for id in output %}
    <tr>
    <form action="execute_fields" method="POST">
      <td><div><label for="to"></label> <input class="input" id="id" type="text" name="id" value="{{id}}"  /></div>  <a href="xxxxxxx/{{id}}/edit" target="_blank" class="btn btn-link"><br><button type="button" class="button is-link">Product on BigCommerce</button></a></td>
      <td><div><label for="to"></label> <textarea class="textarea" name="title" id="title" rows="5"/>{{titles[id]}}</textarea></div></td>
      <td><div><label for="to"></label> <textarea class="textarea" name="fields" id="fields" rows="5"/>{{output[id]}}</textarea></div></td>
      <td><div><button id="status" name="status" onclick="change_text()" class="button is-link">Accept</button></div></td>
</form>
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: One way to create a bunch of unique IDs is to use an index variable in your template loop and insert that into the id. `{% for id, i in output %}` should work. However you have a bunch of forms there, so submitting them all at once either requires a single form with array attributes like `name="title[]"`, or submitting them individually but using ajax and putting the request promise into Promise.all so you can await of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create customizable input based on the trigger then I don't think form would be the best way. Use functions for all the submit button and define the function as per your need, like say, if you click on func1() then you will read data from few input field and push it to the server and if you click func2() then you will get data from all the input field and send it to server.

try this out, if you need code for this then do let me know.